# JavaScript global variable reverts back to original value after change?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I have a global variable `window.current_index` that records the application state, i.e. which page we are on in a javascript web app.

Then I have a block of code that goes to the next page, and increments `window.current_index` to reflect the state change (took out irrelevant DOM manipulation code that just would make it harder to see the issue):

```
$('#next-page').click(function() {
    console.log('current index is ' + window.current_index);
    var next_index = window.current_index + 1;
    console.log('next index is ' + next_index);
    //update the index
    window.current_index = window.current_index + 1;
    console.log('current index is now ' + window.current_index);
});
```

It works fine the first time, but when I click it again, I don't get the intended result. With the console logging, I get an odd output:

```
current index is 2         main.js:57
next index is 3            main.js:59
current index is now 3     main.js:62
current index is 2         main.js:57
next index is 3            main.js:59
current index is now 3     main.js:62
```

It appears that `window.current_index` **hasn't been updated when I fire the function again, even though it said it was before?** Isn't this variable of appropriate scope so that I can store the app state in it and it will persist across the event handler calls? Obviously not since it isn't working... what have I done wrong? I'm guessing this is a scope issue but I can't figure out for the life of me how I would do it correctly... :/

**Clarification:** there is no page reload going on here, page does not reload in between actions. I just show a new "frame" via JavaScript hiding/showing. I'm also not using `iframes`, I'm literally just using `$('div').hide()` and `$('div').show()` on a one-pager site.

Comment: This is not a scoping issue. Web is stateless. So as soon as you switch to a different page, the variable will be reset to the initial value. You would need to use a session variable or use Local storage to accomplish it.

Comment: I never switch to a different page/there is no page reload. All I'm doing is showing a new "frame" via JavaScript hiding/showing.

Comment: If you are using a frame that uses a different URL the same still applies.

Comment: It's not a `iframe` I'm just hiding/showing DOM elements with stuff like `$('div').hide()` and `$('div').show()` etc. that's why I'm thinking this is odd.

Comment: Anyone? **No page reload** and **no iframes** which makes this hard to wrap my head around..

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/sjFrX/. The code you posted looks fine. The problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: @FelixKling There were two event handlers with the same selector, lol. You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me

```
window.current_index = 0;
$('#next-page').click(function() {
    console.log('current index is ' + window.current_index);
    var next_index = window.current_index + 1;
    console.log('next index is ' + next_index);
    //update the index
    window.current_index = window.current_index + 1;
    console.log('current index is now ' + window.current_index);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hHFkJ/1/

Comment: The problem was code elsewhere in the code base.. you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with this code. I had two event handlers that had the same selector, which cause the problem. Feeling dumb...